# ASP.NET5 MVC6: Pass object from view to controller always null

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

EDIT: I am able to pass some plain data if I use type: 'GET' in the ajax call and [HttpGET] in the Controller.

However, complex datatypes like my Summary class is still not working and everything is either 0 or NULL.

I have the following class:

```
public class Summary
    {
        public int Total { get; set; }
        public double Average { get; set; }
        public int Issues { get; set; }
        public int Fixed { get; set; }
        public double FixedPercentage { get; set; }
        public double TotalPercentage { get; set; }
        public List<Issues> IssuesList { get; set; }        
    }

public class Issues
{
       public string Name {get; set;}
       public int Code {get; set;}
}
```

And the following Action on my Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetSummary(Summary summaryBySource)
{
     Json(new
     {
         summary = "hi"
     });
}
```

Lastly, this is the ajax call I am using to return the object to the Controller:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/Summary/GetSummary/',
        data: JSON.stringify(summaryBySource),
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert("Wrong");
        },
        success: function (result) {
            alert("Yeah");

        },
        async: true,
        processData: true
    });
```

Once the ajax call gets called, it jumps into the controller function but all its properties are NULL. Why is that happening?

BTW: the variable summaryBySource is a global variable that is in the View at the moment that the ajax call is called and it contains the values that matches with the Summary object.

Also, I tried to do the same thing but instead of passing an object, just a dumb string and it also returns null...

Thanks!

EDIT: The content of summaryBySource is

It will be an Object type and...

```
Total: 0
Average: 0
Issues: 2
Fixed: 1
FixedPercentage: 50
TotalPercentage: 100
IssuesList: Array[1]
    0: Object
        Name: "Crash"
        Code: 1001
```

Comment: What is the content of `summaryBySource`?

Comment: summaryBySource at ajax call level contains the content that maps with the object defined on my Model. However on the controller it contains 0 for int and double values and null for the List<Issues>. As I said before, even if I just try to pass a string through the data field, it returns null so it must be something else that I am missing...

Comment: But what is the exact content? Show an example.

Comment: Yes, but you have shown us what you think it looks like, not the actual raw data.

Comment: I am not following you now. That's the content coming from the Chrome debugger if I inspect the summaryBySource variable.

Comment: No it's not. For example you say one of your properties is called `List<Issues>`

Comment: Main thread edited. It contains the exact content of the object summaryBySource